# quartz crystal in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

[image]I want to draw a crystal oscillator circuit diagram using circuitikz. How do add crystal? 
I used http://web.mit.edu/outland/share/texmf/doc/latex/circuit_macros/CMman.pdf

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) [xtal] (4,0);       
\end{circuitikz}
```

It does not recognize xtal. Please let me know what should I use?

I want to place "crystal" in the circuit.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE! I suppose `xtal` is a Tikz style. Do you have a more complete code to share? I mean, including the preamble, because we have no way of knowing what that style is about.

Comment: The latest version features PZ or piezoelectric.  I also notice a few other new symbols.

Comment: Could you provide me a link to find symbols in latest version. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample code in circuitikz which includes PZ as suggested by John Kormylo.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (2,0)
        to [Tnpn,n=npn] (2,1.4)
        (npn.E) node[right=3mm, above=5mm]{$Q$}; % Label the transistor
    \draw (2,1) to (2,3) node[circ]{} 
        to [PZ,l=$X_1$] (0,3)
        to [R,l_=$1\Omega$] (0,0.7) node[circ]{}
        to (1.2,0.7);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{My first circuit.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and it gives the following output

[image]

Comment: I am getting error using PZ.

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/PZ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [PZ]

Comment: It works on my desktop[MikTeX latest version] as well as on my MBP[MacTex latest version] without a problem. You may need to update your packages I guess.

Comment: I am using TexLive in Ubuntu. Does it matter? Do MikTex and TexLive have different packages?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as it's latest! TeXLive latest updates are same!

Comment: this still doesn't work for me. Please could u suggest something else

Comment: I got it. I had tested the same on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. It fails however it work if you use the latest circuitikz package. You may follow the discussion at github `https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/46` I'd put up there as an issue to help us!

Comment: This is not a problem of circuitikz, moreover, the ubuntu packages are just too old. Please use a manual installation method for texlive, the the tlmgr-application will be installed(It is missing at the ubuntu-packages!). Use this to update you tex installation regularly, and each year in the summer do a reinstall of the new texlive installation.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Khaaba, i went through your query at github, and tried manually installing texlive-2016. But i am facing problems with installations. Is there a stable version for it yet, if yes where can i get it from?

Comment: Second part of the issue is related to software update. Hence, this question may be closed by choosing/ticking answer as is. Well, Installing texlive 2016 on Ubuntu will solve your problem suggested by sistlind! FYI, latest version of texlive at Ubuntu is 2013.20140215-1 when you use `sudo apt-get install texlive` which will not help you get `PZ` command in circuitkz. So, install TeXlive 2016 from either internet or iso file. For ISO, here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/ and for installing over net:: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Comment: Yes, that's right! Just finish installing TeXlive2016 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after removing default TeXlive 2015! It/PZ works!!